# Passing arguments to a fragment that is referenced by a <fragment> element in the XML resource

Tags: android, arguments, fragment

The usual pattern for passing arguments to a fragment is to define a `newInstance` helper method that calls the fragment's default constructor and then calls `setArguments`, passing a `Bundle`. I understand how this works when the fragment is added dynamically via the `FragmentManager`, because in that case I instantiate the fragment explicitly by calling `newInstance`.

This works when the XML resource for the activity has a *container* for the fragment and does not specify which fragment will be added there later. But what if I want the XML resource for the activity want to refer to the fragment's XML resource, using the `<fragment>` element? In this case, Android calls the fragment's default constructor for me, and I never use the `FragmentManager`. At what point do I provide the arguments in this case, or it it not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By calling `<fragment>` from your xml layout, the default constructor will be fired which means your arguments won't be handled.

In this case, there are many ways to pass data to your fragment:

1. Find the declared fragment using `findFragmentById` then pass
   the data using a setter like any other class.
2. Declare your xml
       fragment with no class, then inflate it programmatically using
       FragmentManager.
3. Use custom attributes to pass data on your xml
       (efficient with primitive data)

Hope that answers your question

Answer (score 2):

As it is being displayed in xml, it has already been constructed. You will need to add a helper method to your fragment class to set the values you want. You can get a reference to your fragment by calling

```
MyFragment mFrag = (MyFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentID);
mFrag.helperMethod(23, "foobar");
```